# EF6 ADO.NET Entity Data Model of MySQL database in VS 2013 Community

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, mysql-connector

Please help. I have fresh installation VS 2013 Community and following dll's downloaded by Nuget:

```
EntityFramework.6.0.0
MySql.Data.6.9.5
MySql.Data.Entity.6.9.5
MySql.Web.6.9.5
```

I have also installed MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.3

In ADO.NET Entity Data Model I can connect to MySQl, but when I click ok, nothing happens and I cannot choose tables (db first approach). I have replaced dll's in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

But It doesn't help. This is my VS solution: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3zNHnJOfYwLODcwNktYbVJGUTA/view?usp=sharing

I have try tips from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280396/mysql-connector-with-ef6-in-visual-studio-2013/28498583#28498583) question, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Before you adding the table does mysql databases listed under your connections. You can try this by going to Tools->Connect to a Database. If not try reinstalling the My Sql for visual studio. I had the same problem but when i installed it again i was seeing the entry of **MySql** so was able to connect to the database.