# Using MySql Provider with Entity Framework Model

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I googled about this topic but I don't really find a solution :

I try this [method](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264) : I installed in my `vs2013` these tools :

1. [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.1](http://href=%22https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1.msi%22)
2. [MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

I Installed also, using NuGet, all MySql library or tools. But I'm still not find the `MySql Provider`.

[image]

So I need to know How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the reference for the required package MySql.*.dll

This helped me:
[stackoverflow mysql connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280396/mysql-connector-with-ef6-in-visual-studio-2013)